# Beep in shell script not working?

Tags: sound, command-line, scripts

I'd like to use a beep sound in a shell script. Unfortunately none of the methods I found via Google work for me.

I tried

```
echo -e '\a'

echo -ne '\007'
```

and the command `beep` after I installed it via apt.

What could be the reason?

Comment: See this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/769314

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/47564/remotely-make-the-computer-beep-on-built-in-speaker || http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/how-do-i-make-my-pc-speaker-beep || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313939/how-to-emit-a-beep-on-my-computer-while-running-a-script-on-a-remote-machine

Comment: ### For a Nice PulseAudio Bell Sound in Xubuntu ###
See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310345/how-to-fix-gnome-terminal-bell-in-xubuntu-20-04

Comment: If your terminal is `terminator`, see my Q&A here for the answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253799/terminator-terminal-wont-play-bell-sound/1253800#1253800.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

First run `sudo modprobe pcspkr` and then `beep` should work.

The reason this doesn't is because by default Ubuntu no longer loads the hardware driver that produce beeps.

If this works for you then to enable the loading of pcspkr permanently edit the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file (using `gksudo gedit` perhaps) and comment out line that says `blacklist pcspkr` so it looks like this:

```
# ugly and loud noise, getting on everyone's nerves; this should be done by a
# nice pulseaudio bing (Ubuntu: #77010)
# blacklist pcspkr
```

Comment: If I comment `blacklist pcspkr` I have to do `modprobe -r pcspkr && modprobe pcspkr` to get it to work. Also getting beep to work is _not_ the same as getting the audible bell to work and thus http://askubuntu.com/questions/22168/how-do-i-enable-the-terminal-bell should still be open.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Ubuntu 14.

Comment: This will mostly likely never work on modern laptops, as they don't have a speaker device.  Instead see my answer below on how to use `paplay`.  (I wasted a bunch of time chasing down this, only to get silence.)

Answer (score 119):

Not being a fan of the pcspkr beep, I use a beep from one of the system sounds with the installed pulseaudio server's paplay command.

First find a sound you like (you can browse /usr/share/sounds for some available ones for example) and create a reference to it

```bash
export BEEP=/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/ringtones/Harmonics.ogg
```

Then have it available as a command

```bash
alias beep='paplay $BEEP'
```

Now just run `beep` whenever you need it. For example, to alert you when a command is finished:

```bash
find . | grep treasure ; beep
```

Comment: Can you get it to play this sound when someone runs `echo -e '\a'`

Comment: You might need some [read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731281/bash-script-listen-for-key-press-to-move-on) command in a while loop or some other library that can monitore keystrokes.

Comment: This is a great solution! Now I can do `run-my-long-test-suite.sh; beep` and read stackoverflow until the system is ready.

Comment: Nice! I use `export BEEP=/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/dialog-information.ogg` and `alias beep='paplay $BEEP --volume=32768'` now, that works well for me. (Note that you can override the volume with the `beep` alias, e.g. `beep --volume=15000` plays at volume of -12dB.)

Comment: Playing these ogg files can result in latency orders of magnitude greater than that of the internal PC speaker beep. Not only that the latency seems highly variable. I acknowledge that most people don't care but when you need real time or near real time responsiveness the PC speaker is probably the best option for audible feedback.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all

Comment: If you like this, you might also like `spd-say "Analysis complete"`

Comment: Unfortunately this approach doesn't work if I want to trigger a beep sound in an SSH session (i.e. from a command in a remote server). However, if I could get the `echo` command to work, then it would be possible: https://serverfault.com/questions/500839/let-the-local-machine-beep-when-some-event-happen-on-remote

Answer (score 30):

Since this is a very high rated question on google, I'll add the steps I did to re-enable beep in both console and X11:

---

### For the Linux Console (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>...<kbd>F6</kbd>):

#### Why it does not work by default

As [already answered](https://askubuntu.com/a/19909/11015), the `pcspkr` kernel driver for the PC Speaker is blacklisted in Ubuntu.

Temporarily enable until reboot:

```
sudo modprobe pcspkr
```

Automatically enable on boot:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

(delete or comment `pcspkr` line by prepending it with `#`)

---

### For X11 terminals (such as the default `gnome-terminal`)

#### Why it does not work by default

Under X, like when using Unity, KDE, Gnome Shell, the beep events are captured by PulseAudio thanks to `module-x11-bell`, which is loaded by default at `/usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11`. And the sound sample PulseAudio plays on beep, `bell.ogg`, is blank by default. Additionally, the bell volume may be muted.

To temporarily enable for current session,

```
xset b 100  # perhaps not needed, on my system it was 40 by default
pactl upload-sample /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg bell.ogg
```

There are other suitable samples you can try at `/usr/share/sounds`, for example check the ones at `/usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/`

Note that the `beep` program is not really necessary. But if installed, it uses the PC Speaker. It was the only way I could find to enable the buzzer under X:

```
sudo apt-get install beep
```

To automatically enable on boot, just add the above lines in your `~/.profile`, or system-wide at `/etc/profile`

---

To test it:

```
printf '\a'
```

*Beep!*

```
beep
```

*Buzz!*

Comment: To automatically enable a pc speaker beep on boot you have to actually **comment** said line in _/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf_ not uncomment it (you want to disable blacklisting, not the other way around).

Comment: both solutions work on Ubuntu 16.04 Note: `pcspkr` and `bell.ogg` are independent approaches. `beep` tries to beep using various approaches e.g., [`ioctl(console_fd, KIOCSOUND, period)`](https://github.com/johnath/beep/blob/0d790fa45777896749a885c3b93b2c1476d59f20/beep.c#L100-L121) use `pcspkr` (the sound is coming from PC speaker on the motherboard) while `printf '\a'` -based method may work without it using only `bell.ogg` (the sound is from ordinary speakers). The second method might not work [until pulseaudio service is started and/or `xset b on` is run](http://askubuntu.com/q/836251/3712)

Comment: The `pactl upload-sample ...` was golden for me. What's the way to permanently configure the sample loading again?

Comment: @ulidtko: Just add those lines lines in your `~/.profile`, or system-wide at `/etc/profile`

Comment: @MestreLion wrong. `load-sample bell.ogg /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg` in `/etc/pulseaudio/default.pa`.

Answer (score 25):

I've encountered this problem before. From what I remember, the problem is that the terminal bell tries to ring an internal computer speaker (as in an old-school desktop) but laptops and some newer computers are missing such a thing.

The only solution I found at the time was to

```
sudo apt-get install sox
```

and

```
play -n synth <duration in seconds> sine <freq in Hz> vol <volume (0-1)>
```

e.g.

```
 play -n synth 0.1 sine 880 vol 0.5
```

Comment: try my solution - I'd love to know if it works for you!

Comment: you may use speaker-test for this too

Comment: You can also have a nice guitar pluck tone: `play -q -n synth 2 pluck C5`. C5 is the note.

Answer (score 23):

To fix this problem persistently:

- Run `gconf-editor` and if the `desktop | gnome | peripherals | keyboard | bell_mode` setting is present then change it from `off` to `on`
- Run `dconf-editor` and if the `org | gnome | settings-daemon | peripherals | keyboard | bell-mode` setting is present then change it from `off` to `on`
- Add `pactl upload-sample /usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/glass.ogg bell.ogg` to the file `~/.xprofile` (you need `gnome-control-center-data` for `glass.ogg`)
- Add `[ "$DISPLAY" ] && xset b 100` to the file `~/.bashrc`

The simplest way to activate this solution is to reboot.

Further, to implement this solution immediately for a terminal window that is already open, run the `pactl` command and run the `xset` command in the terminal window in question.

Comment: I put the `pactl upload-sample` command in a shell script, but your method is more organized. Thanks!

Comment: If you put the `pactl` command in `~/.xprofile` it gets executed at the start of the GUI session.

Comment: The `dconf-editor` version of the `bell-mode` setting seems to be `org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard`.

Comment: @lgarzo: Thanks for the tip. I will update the answer.

Comment: Does not work with Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @Hibou57: Make sure you have the package containing `glass.ogg` installed

Answer (score 9):

"**Beep can only work if your PC has a traditional old style "speaker"**, and probably most if not all laptops and small devices don't have one.

However what they often have instead is a sound chip and one or more speaker(s) that can be used to make any sound you want.

So the outdated advise to install the `beep` command and/or the kernel module `pcspkr` will silently never work when you don't have the old style speaker hardware.

**INSTEAD:**  Try playing a sound like this when you want a beep:

```
paplay /usr/share/sounds/sound-icons/capital
```

Note this uses the `paplay` (**P**ulse **A**udio **Play**) command which mixes better with other user level (user app) sounds on your system, and not the older `aplay` (**A**LSA **Play**) command which generally can only play one sound at the same time.  But note however, that PulseAudio calls ALSA to actually play the sound.

*My previous suggestion to use `play` might still work, but running SoX of which play is from, is overkill.*

---

Works for me when all else failed.  Thanks to: [tredegar](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-play-beep-sound-inside-shell-script-895465/#post4433944) & [hk_centos](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-play-beep-sound-inside-shell-script-895465/#post4434270) and others.

Answer (score 4):

I finally found a solution, which doesn't require `alsamixer` to have a PC Beep option. I think I remember all my changes:

uncomment the following in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
load-sample-lazy x11-bell /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg
load-module module-x11-bell sample=bell-windowing-system
```

per [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/769314), run `pactl upload-sample /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg bell.ogg`

Comment: Tried this, pactl gave me `Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused`.

Comment: Maybe [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=119100) will help - if you've ever run pulseaudio as root.

Comment: I'm having a different problem, actually. Pulseaudio throws `Failed to open module "module-esound-protocol-unix": file not found`. Probably not worth discussing here since I'm running 13.04, though I would love to be able to verify your solution.

Comment: Nice, just slightly different lines for 15.04.

Answer (score 3):

It might be to late BUT, for the guy in the future looking for this:

```
printf '\x07'
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, this is a bug: [System beep broken in Karmic despite heroic efforts to fix it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/486154).

Comment: "Not enabled by default" does not mean broken, and no "heroic effort" is needed: just `modprobe pcsprk` (in console) or `pactl upload-sample ...` in X11 and the annoying beep is back :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have actual speakers connected to the computer and you're not getting a beep it's likely because you are using compiz. Compiz is relying on pulseaudio catching the beeps and playing them while metacity bypasses the usual setup and uses libcanberra to play a beep sound. If it works with metacity and not compiz that is your problem, otherwise the answer htorque gave is corrent.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach - set your xterm / console to "Visual Bell" so that when it would beep, the window simply inverts its colours for a short time.

I have a bash function called beep to get my attention once a command is finished.

```
beep ()  { while true; do  echo -en '\a'; sleep 1; done }
```

And it is used this way

```
longrun-command ; beep
```

Answer (score 2):

I added this little function to my .bashrc as a replacement for beep:

```
beep () {
    if [ "$1" = --list ]
    then
        find /usr/share/sounds -type f -exec basename {} \; | sort -n | tr '\n' ' '; echo
    else
        paplay $(find /usr/share/sounds -type f -iname "${1:-bell}*" | head -1)
    fi
}
```

It searches for a file in /usr/share/sounds starting with supplied argument or "bell" and plays it. `beep --list` returns list of files in /usr/share/sounds.

```
# Examples
beep
beep bark
beep trump
```

Answer (score 1):

```
paplay /usr/share/sounds/purple/alert.wav
```

Answer (score 1):

Today, **June 2020**, in **Ubuntu 18.04**, the whole `sudo modprobe pcspkr` and commenting out of the `blacklist pcspkr` part of the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file, [as described here](https://askubuntu.com/a/19909/327339), doesn't seem to be necessary.

Mine is still blacklisted, yet my bell character sound works just fine!

```
$cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf 
.
.
.
# ugly and loud noise, getting on everyone's nerves; this should be done by a
# nice pulseaudio bing (Ubuntu: #77010)
blacklist pcspkr
```

Instead, just make sure the **Terminal bell** sound is turned ON in your `gnome-terminal` settings:

**Right-click on the screen in `gnome-terminal` --> Preferences --> check the box for "Terminal bell" under the "Sound" section**, as shown below:

[image]

Now run this, and hear the dull "thud" sound of the bell character sound:

```
echo -e "\a"
```

This also works over remote ssh sessions, which is super handy when building on a remote machine, for instance, so that it will play the bell sound when the build is done, to alert you:

```
time bazel build //...; echo -e "\a"
```

Also note that pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> when there's nothing to delete will also play this sound in `gnome-terminal`.

## Related:

1. [`terminator` terminal won't play bell sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253799/terminator-terminal-wont-play-bell-sound/1253800#1253800)
2. Update: Also see @jvriesem's response to my question in the comments under this question here: [How do I enable the terminal bell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22168/how-do-i-enable-the-terminal-bell). I seem to be answering a slightly different question.

Answer (score 1):

Some motherboards don't have a beep speaker. To get around this, I created a Python script that instead uses FFmpeg's `aevalsrc` filter to generate beep noises.

Note: you will need to install FFmpeg using `sudo apt install ffmpeg`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# This program runs FFPlay to generate beeps.

from argparse import ArgumentParser, ArgumentError, Action
import re
import subprocess

# Custom action for note
class NoteToFrequencyAction(Action):
    _note = re.compile(r"([A-G])(bb|[bx#])?(\d+)")
    _note_factors = {
        "C": lambda x: x / (2 ** (9/12)),
        "D": lambda x: x / (2 ** (7/12)),
        "E": lambda x: x / (2 ** (5/12)),
        "F": lambda x: x / (2 ** (4/12)),
        "G": lambda x: x / (2 ** (2/12)),
        "A": lambda x: x,
        "B": lambda x: x * (2 ** (2/12)),
    }
    _accidental_factors = {
        "x" : lambda x: x * (2 ** (2/12)),
        "#" : lambda x: x * (2 ** (1/12)),
        None: lambda x: x,
        "b" : lambda x: x / (2 ** (1/12)),
        "bb": lambda x: x / (2 ** (2/12))
    }
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string) -> None:
        if not (isinstance(values, str)):
            raise ArgumentError("Should not have multiple values")
        
        parse = self._note.fullmatch(values);
        parts = parse.groups()

        freq = 440.0
        freq *= 2 ** (int(parts[2]) - 4)
        freq = self._note_factors[parts[0]](freq)
        freq = self._accidental_factors[parts[1]](freq)
        
        if not type(namespace.__dict__[self.dest]) == list:
            namespace.__dict__[self.dest] = []
        namespace.__dict__[self.dest].append(freq)


        

parser = ArgumentParser()

freq_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
freq_group.add_argument("-f", "--frequency", type=float, action="append", dest="freqs",
    help="Can be specified more than once, specifies frequencies in Hz of the beeped notes"
)
freq_group.add_argument("-n", "--note", action=NoteToFrequencyAction, dest="freqs",
    help="Can be specified more than once, specifies notes (e.g. A4). You can use b, #, x, bb for accidentals."
)

parser.add_argument("-d", "--duration", type=float, default=1, dest="time",
    help="The duration of the beep in seconds."
)
parser.add_argument("-v", "--volume", type=float, default=0.5,
    help="The volume of the beep, defaults to 0.5"
)

args = parser.parse_args()
del parser, freq_group

aevalsrc_waves = [f"sgn(sin({repr(f)}*2*PI*t))" for f in args.freqs]
aevalsrc_expr = "+".join(aevalsrc_waves)
ffplay_filter = f"aevalsrc=({aevalsrc_expr})/{len(args.freqs)}*{args.volume}:d={args.time}"
print("aevalsrc filter:")
print(ffplay_filter)

subprocess.run([
    "ffplay", "-f", "lavfi", "-i", ffplay_filter, "-autoexit", "-nodisp"
], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

Simply paste into `~/bin/beep` and `chmod +x beep` to make it available. It doesn't quite support the same options, but doing that would make this code a lot longer than it already is.

Answer (score 0):

This answer works for me using Ubuntu Server with Cinnamon desktop environment installed.  The terminal bell was not working by default.

My solution is similar to the [answer by @jdthood](https://askubuntu.com/a/228278/): I was able to fix it by toggling `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/audible-bell` to `true` using `dconf-editor`.

Answer (score 0):

Some users experiencing the issue in question will only need to open up the Settings GUI, navigate to 'Sound', and under 'Volume Level' increase 'System Sounds' to a nonzero value ( and double-check that 'System Volume' is also nonzero ).

If anyone wants me to add a screenshot, let me know.