# How do I enable the terminal bell?

Tags: command-line, sound, terminal-bell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Beep in shell script not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19906/beep-in-shell-script-not-working)

When using the Terminal application in Ubuntu I never seem to hear any alerts.  How do I turn these sounds on?

I've tried looking in Edit > Profile Preferences and confirming that "Terminal Bell" is checked (which it is.) I've also checked System > Preferences > Sound and I'm using the default Ubuntu them with the "Alert Volume" cranked.  Music and video sound fine.

To simulate a bell I've tried irssi, typing `echo -e "\a"`, hitting tab and backspace but nothing seems to make a sound.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Here's the [most complete answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/587311/20358) I've seen.

Comment: A terminal bell isn't the same as a system beep...this should not be marked as a duplicate. See note in the other question.

Comment: @jvriesem, what do you mean? Both questions use `echo -e "\a"` to test if it is working or not, so how are they not the same?

Comment: @GabrielStaples: A terminal bell is what `echo -e "\a"` should produce. A terminal bell goes to the output speakers like any other sound, and it is affected by the system volume. Terminals often have a setting to flash the terminal window instead of an audible terminal bell. A system beep uses the *internal* computer speaker, *separate* from the output speaker -- it's the 8-bit sound you may hear when a PC boots up -- and you don't control the volume. I believe that when I commented, the question somebody thought this was a duplicate of was talking about system beeps, not terminal bells.