# Internal speaker not working

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-netbook, updates, hp, speakers

My internal speaker was working before I updated(including new kernel) a few days ago. Now it seems that my internal speaker is muted and only external speakers are working . I am using ubuntu 10.10 with my dv6000 laptop. I tried to fix the problem with alsamixer and it looks like I don't have my speaker muted. 
When I check from problems in Preferences -> Sound I am getting :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would you please start gnome-volume-control and check the tab "Output"?

Comment: Ya I did check gnome-volume-control . Output is not muted.

Comment: And in that tab ("Output") what devices you have that you can choose?

Comment: @desgua I have edited my question to add the screenshots . Thanks.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/19906/beep-in-shell-script-not-working and http://askubuntu.com/questions/96511/getting-the-pc-speaker-to-beep

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try this on a terminal:

```
 sudo alsaconf
```

Comment: I am getting the error
 `sudo: alsaconf: command not found`

Comment: I'm on my mobile right now, but I think this may help: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=205449