# Getting the PC speaker to beep

Tags: speakers

There has been much written on getting the beep sound from Ubuntu releases over the years.  Example: [fixing the beep](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/486154)

My needs are slightly different in that I do not want to ensure sound card beeps are functioning.  Instead, I want PC speaker beeps, the kind produced by the original built-in speaker because I believe they will produce less CPU load.  I have confirmed that my computer has the PC speaker by unplugging the external speakers and shutting down Ubuntu.  At some point in the shutdown and restart process a beep is heard even though the external speakers have no power.

I have tried the following:

In `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, turn these lines into comments:

```
#blacklist snd_pcsp
#blacklist pcspkr
```

In `.bashrc`

```
/usr/bin/xset b on
/usr/bin/xset b 100
```

Enable in the gnome terminal: Edit > Profile Prefs > General > Terminal Bell

Ensure no "mute" selections in: System > Prefs > Sound > various tabs (uncheck them all).

Select "Enable window and button sounds" in: System > Prefs > Sound > Sound Effects

In `gconf-editor` desktop > gnome > sound, select the three sound check boxes.

In `gconf-editor` apps > metacity > general select the `audible bell` check box.

Still I get no PC speaker beeps when I send code 7 to the console via my Java program or use

```
echo -e '\a'
```

or equivalently

```
echo -e "\a"
```

on the bash command line. (The -e option means enable escape sequence interpretation.) What else should I try?

**Update** Since my goal is to minimize load on the CPU, here is a comparison of elapsed times.  Each test is for 100,000 iterations.  Each variant was performed three times so three results are presented for each.

```
printwriter.format("%c", 7); 
// 1.3 seconds, 1.5 seconds, 1.5 seconds

Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep(); 
// 0.8 seconds, 0.3 seconds, 0.5 seconds

try { Runtime.getRuntime().exec("beep"); } catch (IOException e) { } 
// 10.3 seconds, 16.3 seconds, 11.4 seconds
```

These runs were done inside Eclipse so multiply by some value less than 1 for standalone execution.  Unfortunately, Toolkit's beep is silent on my computer and so is code 7.  The beep utility works but has the most cost.

Comment: I want "echo -e '\a'" to work, too. Because I want to know if a script has termined: foo-script.py; while true; do echo -e '\a'; done

Comment: I guess your search for a solution (reduce cpu usage) has already created a lot of cpu cycles.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On 14.04.3 LTS it nows seems sufficient to edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and enable `pcspkr` by commenting out the blacklist line.

```
#blacklist pcspkr
```

The `#` turns the line into a comment.

Make sure the Terminal (`gnome-terminal`) allows console bell in the preferences tab.

This was tested via backspace on an empty terminal line. This was also tested via the `beep` utility (assuming that you have installed it). Instead you can do programmatic beeping via the java.awt.Toolkit object: `java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep()`.

The Toolkit object is more efficient than the `beep` utility.

By the way, [some people dislike the PC speaker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/module-init-tools/+bug/77010).

Answer (score 6):

On my Oneiric system I had to do the following to get XBell/XkbBell working again:

1. Load the module `pcspkr` (like you already did via `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`)
2. Remove the package `pulseaudio-module-x11` (that seems to absorb all XBell events)
3. Put `options snd-hda-intel beep_mode=2` into `/etc/modprobe.d/enable-beep.conf` (you only need that case you own a system with an intel sound chip like my Latitude E6420). Unmute the speaker in alsamixer after that.

Some terminals (like konsole, see bug [Bug 177861](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=177861)) ignore the bell character. A good way to test the system beep is with the `xkbbell` command.

After I did all that the java call `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep()` works just fine.

Comment: That works for me, by just loading kernel module `sudo modprobe pcspkr`, It does work with `echo -e '\a'`, `xkbbell`, `beep` and using `XBell()` & `XkbBell()` c functions. Some posts montion requirement of`module-x11-bell` with pulseaudio, I unloaded it and it worked. One thing that I could find to stop it is `dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/audible-bell false` or from *Compiz>GeneralOptions>AudibleBell*. As it seems for now, the bell is a Windows Manager task. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Thank you! My Dell 7270 beeps like a boss!

Answer (score 1):

[Make sure](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/486154) your terminal and theme don't eat the event.

[External tools](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1362) work, you say. You could dive into their code. [This](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2001-February/003625.html) might help.

Comment: Thanks, I looked a bit into coding the solution. It looks simple, just play with a few hardware ports. Unfortunately, Java probably does not give you hardware port I/O the way C/C++ do.

Comment: [The Java Native Interface can play tones via the PC speaker.](http://mindprod.com/products2.html#SPEAKER)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`beep` program](https://github.com/spkr-beep/beep). I've compiled the v1.3, because the 1.2.2  in Lucid repositories do not work.

- you need to run it with `sudo`
- the pcspkr module must be loaded, as you all ready did

Comment: I don't think you need sudo for the beep utility. The trouble with it is that `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("beep");` is how I have been doing it in Java. Might be slow compared to code 7 to the standard output.

Comment: without sudo gives
Could not open /dev/tty0 or /dev/vc/0 for writing
open: No such file or directory