# How do I make the 'beep' command work?

Tags: 10.04, compiz, sound

I am trying to use the `beep` command, but it doesn't beep any sound.

I installed it with `sudo apt-get install beep`, then I ran `beep` and nothing happen (no error displayed or sound played). I've also ran `sudo modprobe pcspkr`, and `sudo alsamixer`, unmuted "beep" and put the db gain to 100. And `sudo alsactl store` after that.

Is there a way to fix it or an alternative to `beep`?

I am using Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Not a "real" solution but this is what I do: alias b='r -l "beepr" -e "beep(0)"', then use `b`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does it *have* to be the system beep or can it be any sound?

You have a command on your system to play command line sounds.
For instance open a terminal with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> and

```
cd /usr/share/sounds/alsa/
aplay Front_Center.wav
```

will play this `Front_Center.wav`.

So all you need is to find a `beep.wav` on the web and use `aplay` with it.

Comment: Yea i end up using aplay, dont know why beep is not working, thanks for your reply.

Comment: The point of `beep` is that it can generate any arbitrary beep.

Comment: @Rinzwind and another downvote 5 years later, for not answering the question

Comment: "or an alternative to beep?" hmmm?

Answer (score 13):

although over 2 years old i found using [beep](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/beep.1.html) still to be an issue on my ubuntu 12.04 based system.

after making sure the beep mixer level is > 0 through `alsamixer` the solution to a similar question at [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/19909/44653) worked fine for me; it boils down to un-blacklisting the `pcspkr` module in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. Or you can just do `sudo modprobe pcspkr` for a temporary solution.

as described in the accepted answer a more pleasant audible notification could be achieved through playing some notification sounds present by default on most systems such as (for gnome based systems) e.g. `paplay /usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/glass.ogg`

note that `paplay` (using pulse audio) might nowadays be the way to go instead of the alsa-based (but still working) `aplay`.

Comment: "a more pleasant audible notification could be achieved" ... *if* your computer has a sound card and speakers.