# Beep command works but the bell character doesn't

Tags: command-line, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

After reading this answer, the `beep` command successfully makes a sound.

https://askubuntu.com/a/168628/445574

But when I print the bell character, it doesn't make any.

I've already tried:
https://superuser.com/questions/615839/beep-works-but-the-bell-character-makes-no-sound

Basically, `printf '\a'` and `echo -e "\a"` don't beep.

- I have removed the blacklist pcspkr from `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
- I have entered the command `sudo modprobe pcspkr`
- `beep` makes a sound

Comment: That [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/168628/445574) you refer to re-aliases `beep` to `paplay <something>`, so that is no proof that the `beep` command works for you. What happens when you run `/usr/bin/beep`?

Answer (score 0):

Just struggled with this for a few days, try this

```
$ alsamixer
```

then scroll over to beep and turn up the volume if down, also make sure to press M to unmute it (will change it too 00 instead of MM) then give it another try make sure to unmute anything else that is need headphone, speakers hope it helps!